# splitting string based on multiple criteria

Tags: r

If I had strings such as:

```
example 1: email:none@blank.com,username:noneusername, token:nonetoken21309r9023, user_id:nonuserid

example 2: username:slkfsoi,email:kljasdf@asflk.com,username:oiwoie,token:asfkjsdf0

example 3: email:slfkjsaf@asfdlk.com,user_id:lkasflk
```

I want to split based on email, username, token and user_id.  In some cases, not all 4 are present.  Plus, in other instances, a string could have multiple instances of each (email,token,email,user_id,token).  In which case, I want to take the first instance of each.

Here's what I have for R, however, if I use it in a loop, it is not efficient when there are thousands of strings in the dataframe.  I tried using this function with apply, however, it would not work.  I think it's because my function is not vectorized?

```
match_value <- function(x,z){
  b <- head(grep(z,unlist(strsplit(x,","))),1)
  c <- strsplit(x, ",")
  d <- unlist(c)[b]
  e <- gsub(z,"",d)
  if((length(e) == 0) && (typeof(e) == "character")){
   e = ""
  }
  return(e)
}
```

In the example above, I would call the function such as where x = dataframe column of string value, and z = string I want to match, such as email: or token:.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use your approach but using `gsub` and a regular expression

```
x <- c('email:none@blank.com,username:noneusername, token:nonetoken21309r9023, user_id:nonuserid',
       'username:slkfsoi,email:kljasdf@asflk.com,username:oiwoie,token:asfkjsdf0',
       'email:slfkjsaf@asfdlk.com,user_id:lkasflk')

f <- function(what, string = x) {
  gsub(sprintf('%s\\:\\s*([^,]*)|.', what), '\\1', string, perl = TRUE)
}


f('email', x)
# [1] "none@blank.com"      "kljasdf@asflk.com"   "slfkjsaf@asfdlk.com"

f('username', x)
# [1] "noneusername"  "slkfsoioiwoie" ""             

f('token', x)
# [1] "nonetoken21309r9023" "asfkjsdf0"           ""                   

f('user_id', x)
# [1] "nonuserid" ""          "lkasflk"  


n <- c('email', 'username', 'token', 'user_id')
data.frame(setNames(lapply(n, f), n))

#                 email      username               token   user_id
# 1      none@blank.com  noneusername nonetoken21309r9023 nonuserid
# 2   kljasdf@asflk.com slkfsoioiwoie           asfkjsdf0          
# 3 slfkjsaf@asfdlk.com                                     lkasflk
```